# push/pull extending rod

Tags: actuator

Will start off by saying I know very little about electrical engineering :/

so I basically need to make some sort of push/pull extending rod

it Doesn't have to be particularly strong, just needs to sort of hold the weight of an apple

the only problem is it needs to use a 12v power supply, iv'e looked everywhere and can't find a single reference as to where to either buy or try and attempt to make such a thing.

it needs to extend/detract about the length of an iphone 6 (sorry about the weird measurements, it was a rushed job)

if anyone could point me in the right direction or offer a little bit of advice it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So, take a stick of several inches in length and tape (or glue or nail) an apple to the end and then move it back and forth. Now I know you are not here to expect that as an answer but it's the only thing that springs to mind having read your question. Try revamping your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making a rack and pinion mechanism. Consider the image given below:

[image: rack n pinion]

I am suggesting this because most of the parts are readily available in hobby robotics store. Buy a toothed rack and stick it to a wooden strip. Use whatever length you want. Do it on both sides as shown. You will need three spur gears which will make the rack move back and forth. Two gears will be mounted on dead shafts (use a motor if not able to find dead shaft). One gear will be mounted on a DC motor. That's it. Your push/pull extending rod is ready.

Note: Double sided rack and three gears have been used to bring stability to the structure. Make sure rack is hanging a little on both sides while operating so ensure a smooth operation.

Comment: You may also want to introduce some protection for the motor/circuits to prevent someone from pushing or pulling the rod by hand. You could use a worm gear so that the arm can only be moved by the motor rotating the worm gear. You would also get a speed reduction using a worm gear but the question doesn't provide information as to whether a quick push/pull is required...

Comment: thanks, this seems like the best solution for the task at hand ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Scrap car parts might provide a source of useful 12 V actuators. You could try an electric window-winder mechanism (much longer stroke than you want), an electric mirror acutator (much shorter than you want), rear window-wiper mechanism (would require a linear guide but stroke could be adjusted by moving the distance of the linkage from the centre of the wiper.

It may be in your interest to provide more details ...

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. Car mechanisms tend to operate on 12V. It could be also suggested to look into electric seat adjusters. These use quite nice motor with lead screw or worm gear drive. And range of motion is almost perfect.

Comment: ....but it is designed to operate for short time, so heating-up fast.

Comment: It depends on the load. His apple wouldn't be as difficult to move as you or me. The seat actuator should be fine but probably worth keeping an eye on the motor temperature.